# isUserAdmin semantic in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

The function call **UserServiceFactory.getUserService().isUserAdmin()** returns boolean indicating if the user is an administrator for this application. What does that mean exactly ?

- the user is administrator for the Google Apps
  domain used to authenticate ?
- the user is owner of the application at appengine.google.com ?
- something else ?

The javadoc is not clear to me ....

**isUserAdmin**
boolean **isUserAdmin()**

**Returns** true if the user making this request is an admin for this application, false otherwise.
**Throws:**
java.lang.IllegalStateException - If the current user is not logged in.

Comment: I am using OpenId authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this means the user is a user who has been added with **any** role at appengine.google.com.

[image]

The details of the roles is [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/roles.html)

Also everyone who is added as an Admin in the app console if running on your own domain is an admin I believe.

Comment: Ouch, I got ninja-answered, and yours come with pretty pictures too. +1 :)

Comment: @IbrahimArief yes, ninja answered by Sam. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your app engine dashboard, on the section Application -> Permission. I believe isUserAdmin() will return true if the user is registered on this page with one of the roles.

[More info at the official docs about roles](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/roles.html).